# How to get a random letter in Java?

Tags: java, random, character, offset

I want to get a random letter using something like

```
char ch = 'A' + randomNumber ;  // randomNumber is int from 0 to 25
```

But that gives "loss of precision" compilation error (same if randomNumber is only a byte).
I guess with Unicode the above is a gross oversimplification.

This works but seems a bit clumsy:

```
char ch = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".charAt(randomNumber);
```

How should I do it ?

Comment: couldn't you just make randomNumber a char? This way the compiler won't complain

Comment: The compiler complains anyway, because the + operator produces an int that you have to cast.

Answer (score 6):

`char ch = (char) (new Random().nextInt('Z' - 'A' + 1) + 'A')`

You may replace 'A' and 'Z' by any character you want to achieve a wider range.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is arising from trying to assign an `int` into a `char`.

Since an `int` is 32-bits and `char` is 16-bits, assigning an `int` can potentially lead to a loss of precision, hence the error message is displayed at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you're going to be in the appropriate range, just cast:

```
char ch = (char) ('A' + randomNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the cleanest way to get what I want so it is obvious at a glance what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Ugly casting but no compilation errors. Should generate a random capital letter:

```
int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
int i = 65 + (rand % 26);
char c = (char) i;
System.out.println(c);
```